# Azure. Looking for a way to quickly deploy complex environments

Tags: azure

I’m in a constant need of deploying complex Azure infrastructures as soon as possible. And because time is a very precious resource I’m looking for your advice on what approach I should learn. For example, I need to deploy 2 storage accounts, 10 VMs that consist of SQL Servers HA clusters, web servers and all of that into domain. Of course it’s a pain to do that manually more than once. So I’m looking for an easy to learn and fast to deploy way to do all that. What are my options and what is best practice for such situations?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

a combination of two things will help you here. you should use a combination of .Json templates and PowerShell desired state configuration(PowerShell DSC)

.json will allow you to deploy your VMs, Storage accounts, resource groups, Vnets etc. by defining each element in a .json file. you will build the .json files once and then use them to repeatedly role out the same environment over and over again. take a look at this blog for an initial look at .json

https://azurestack.eu/2015/06/azure-resource-manager-templates-json/

using .json file to deploy most of your config should give you predictable results every time.

PowerShell DSC can be used to configure your deployed resources and keep them configured. this blog can give you an overview of DSC

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/privatecloud/2013/08/30/introducing-powershell-desired-state-configuration-dsc/

also check out channel Certification and Beyond on YouTube it has lots of videos on DSC.

hope this helps.

Mike.